# Outlook Integration And Lightning Sync

Tags: lightning, integration, outlook, lightning-sync-configurations

I am trying to Test "Outlook Integration And Lightning Sync" with my private MS office 365(not work or school), I selected OAuth 2.0 in Salesforce Lightning Sync setting and try to login to get back tenant ID. However, I get this error :  Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Salesforce' and cannot access the application 'c55d6177-918e-4745-96d3-1715194bc7e8' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.

Any idea if Outlook Integration And Lightning Sync works only with Work and school account or I forgot something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the following edition of Office 365 for setting up Lightning Sync using OAuth 2.0: Office 365®, Enterprise Editions with, Exchange Online. Check this out: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_exchange_sync_admin_implementation_guide.pdf

Comment: thankyou, missed that, trail account doesn't work